# Membership.GetUser giving me an error when logging in

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to set the IP address of a user logging in to my website. This is in the code behind of the login.aspx page and is giving me a server error:

```
(An unhandled exception has occurred. Stack trace:    
at login.LoginUser_LoggingIn(Object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin()
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Protected Sub LoginUser_LoggedIn(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles LoginUser.LoggedIn

    Dim CurrentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser()

    CurrentUser.Comment = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your membership provider?

Comment: <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [LoggedIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event is raised after the authentication provider checks the user's credentials and the authentication cookie is queued to send to the browser in the next response. If you want to get current user at this moment of time you need to call him as

```
Dim currentUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(LoginUser.UserName)
```